# How do I translate a body along it's angle in a physics simulation? I'm using matter js but I think this is mainly math

Tags: game-physics, physics, physics-engine, matter.js

If I have a square body that has been rotated say 45 degrees, and an position x,y at the center of that square, on the 2d plane.

How do I translate that body 40 increments along the angle?

Comment: How about computing the destination x, y vector with the typical `x = Math.cos(angle) * 40` (respectively sin for y) and call [translate](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_translate)?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Thanks.